# How to prevent event propagation on a <button /> element?

Tags: javascript, button, event-propagation

I have a `button` element with a `span` tag inside:

```
<button onClick={this.doSomething.bind(this)}>
   <span>Some text</span>
</button>
```

The `doSomething` function is as follows:

```
function doSomething(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.target.classList.contains("disabled")){
        return false;
    }

    // Continue with button action...
}
```

When the button has the `disabled` class I do not want the button to fire. Currently, when the rim of the button is clicked it does not fire. However, when the inner part of the button is clicked (where the text is) it fires - I want to avoid this - how do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using disabled attribute of a button instead of a class. 
[disabled attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled)

Then you could still style button using:

```
.button[disabled] or button[disabled]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the clicked element, the SPAN, is the event `target`, rather than the BUTTON, which is the currentTarget. Check the class for the `event.currentTarget` instead:

```js
function doSomething(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('triggered', e.target, e.currentTarget);
  if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains("disabled")) {
    console.log('Exit');
    return false;
  }
  console.log('Continue'); // Continue with button action...
}
```

```css
button.disabled span {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doSomething(event)" class="disabled">
  <span>Some text</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it with CSS rule:

```
button.disabled span {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or even:

```
button.disabled * {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

```js
function doSomething(e){
    
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.target.classList.contains("disabled")){
        return false;
    }
    
    console.log('triggered', e.target);

    // Continue with button action...
}
```

```css
button.disabled span {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doSomething(event)" class="disabled">
   <span>Some text (Disabled)</span>
</button>

<button onclick="doSomething(event)" class="">
   <span>Some text</span>
</button>
```